# Add viewport specific styling right in the html tag

Tags: html, css, styles

I was just wondering if it was possible to add styling directly in an html tag that is viewport specific. I know I can define an external stylesheet/internal stylesheet and use @media tags, but if there is a way to put it directly in the

`<div style""></div>`

That would be cool to know. Thanks!

Comment: why would you want to do this?  It would just make your code harder to maintain

Comment: I've made generic classes that I use throughout my pages and needed minor modifications to one of the classes. Thanks for the related post :)

Comment: you should then add another class to that element and add the css to your stylesheet that way you can see all the styles applied to your element for that breakpoint in the same place

Comment: Yeah that seems like the next logical step. Either that or adding an id to the element